# Plural verb with "everybody/anybody/everyone/anyone"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

- Where have everybody/everyone gone to?
- Have anybody/anyone ever told her the truth?

Are these valid usages, idiomatic?

Comment: No. Those pronouns are singular. There are exceptions, like tag questions, but in normal sentences like these, plural is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "has" in each case. (My personal bias is not to use the / in the examples, so I will split them.)

- Where has everyone gone to?
- Where has everybody gone to?
- Has anyone ever told her the truth?
- Has anybody ever told her the truth?

In each case, the "one" or "body" word is a pronoun, and singular.